# Call a class function from the same class function without using self in python

Tags: python

I need to call a method from another method of the same class in python .

I can't use self due to some limitation .

When I am trying to do following .

```
def get_report_by_region(self, report_type, ids, business_unit, region):
    if report_type == "courses":
        request_name = "_get_reports_course_region"
    elif report_type == "certifications":
        request_name = "_get_reports_certificate_region"
    elif report_type == "learning_path":
        request_name = "_get_reports_learning_path_region"
    data = {
        'ids': ids,
        'businessunit': business_unit,
        'regioncode': region}
    result = self.get_individual_report_by_region(data,request_name)
    return result
@staticmethod
@cached_by_signature(time=memcached.MINUTE)
def  get_individual_report_by_region(data,request_name):
    result = MoodleClient.get(request_name, params=data)
    return result
```

I am getting the error

```
 result = MoodleClient.get(request_name, params=data)
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with MoodleClient instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

all the above method are defined inside the class

```
MoodleClient
```

Comment: Methods need an instance to operate on. What instance would you get the result *from*?

Comment: If you have a singleton `MoodleClient` object, then retrieve that as a global and call the method on that singleton instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I could not get you

Comment: Then *what instance* would the method use to draw state from? If you have multiple `MoodleClient()` instances, which one determines where the data is retrieved from?

Comment: why is `get_individual_report_by_region` static? solely for caching purposes?

Comment: "due to some limitation" - what kind of limitation? If it's religious or political, this question is more suitable for programmers.stackexchange. If it's technical, feel free to tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `get()` method is an instance method.

It either needs to be static in the same fashion as `get_individual_report_by_region()` or you need to provide an instance of `MoodleClient`.

You have to think whether it can be static method at all - if you need an instance state, then you cannot make it static.